# Failed to add worker node on external network to Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, bare-metal

Hello I am currently running a Kubernetes cluster at home with 1 master node and 1 worker node. I tried to add instances running on Oracle Cloud as worker nodes to this Kubernetes cluster. I port-forwarded all the ports listed in the official documentation on the router at home, and I did the same for the Oracle Cloud firewall.

After that, I tried to add a node of Oracle Cloud to the cluster using the kubeadm join command (I entered the public ip of the master node ip), but an error related to the X509 certificate occurred (an error that the X509 certificate does not match the public ip), so Added public ip. (After extracting the configuration file through 'kubectl get configmap kubeadm-config -n kube-system -o jsonpath='{.data.ClusterConfiguration}' > kubeadm-conf.yaml' command and adding certSANs, public and private ip in the lower part added) X509 certificate error does not occur anymore, but the following error occurs

ubuntu@a1-worker:~$ sudo kubeadm join (public-ip):6443 --token q4a65r.r32wc9cdwtv83jzj --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:eea8ad19b5d7484ea86f5c06bf993a83b602d44df1aa9c1728ead596e49a7dde --cri-socket=/var/run/crio/crio.sock W0808 16:19:57.287856 1033278 initconfiguration.go:120] Usage of CRI endpoints without URL scheme is deprecated and can cause kubelet errors in the future. Automatically prepending scheme "unix" to the "criSocket" with value "/var/run/crio/crio.sock". Please update your configuration! [preflight] Running pre-flight checks [preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster... [preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml' error execution phase preflight: unable to fetch the kubeadm-config ConfigMap: failed to get config map: Get "https://172.30.1.4:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kubeadm-config?timeout=10s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers) To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

Can you tell me what further steps I need to take here?

I tried replacing the node's private ip with the public ip by editing the node's settings. Also, to solve the X509 problem, the key of the api server was regenerated by adding the public ip of the master node.